# Is there a way to fix weights and biases for a node in keras?

Tags: keras, neural-network, constraints

I am training an ANN model which must produce positive predictions ( e.g. length of some objects ). The way I am planning to implement this constraint is to attach a one-node layer (output layer) at the end to an existing neural network and designate zero bias to this output node. I wonder how I can 'fix' the weights and biases for nodes/layers during training process.

Answer (score 0):

see "https://keras.io/api/layers/constraints/", by these commands you can set constraints for the weights and biases in each layer.
Here, as you want set a bias to zero, this may works :

```
model.add(Dense(1 ,bias_constraint=tf.keras.constraints.MinMaxNorm(
min_value=0.0, max_value=0.0, rate=1.0, axis=0), activation='softmax'))
```